# Java thread lock on System.err()

Tags: java, multithreading, stderr

I'm a little baffled.

I have two threads writing to `System.err` (and `System.out`), and eventually they get stuck in a thread lock. Are `System.err` and `System.out` really not thread-safe?

The structure of the program at that point is:

- main thread having launched two `Reader` threads to do some processing and printout, called via a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.
- one `Reader` thread ("s3gp-2") that is blocked on `System.err.format()`, from within a separate `IOStats` object, in a synchronized method called `IOStats.add()`.
- another `Reader` thread that is (correctly) blocked trying to call the same `IOStats.add()` method that is blocked on `System.err.format()`.

Note that each `Reader` typically writes to `System.err` and `System.out`.

Should I have a separate singleton object that handles all output with synchronized methods?  Any insight very appreciated, as usual.

---

**Update**

I realize that I should give a bit more context: that java program is invoked in parallel by all the n segments of a Greenplum DB (via a `create external web table ... execute prgm`).  The locking behavior is extremely rare and usually all goes well.  When the problem occurs, all the n processes are blocked.  I am focusing on just one of them for the debugging.

Some more notes:

1. For a few minutes, I thought that the fact that I also use `log4j.Logger` might cause trouble. But, in fact, there is no Console appender used for that program so I'm less inclined to think that is the problem.
2. using `lsof` as well as `ls -l /proc/$pid/fd`, I observe that the stderr of the java process that is blocked in a pipe that is also read by postgres. As one commenter suggested, it might be that this pipe is not actually drained by postgres, and that blocks the `System.err` print out.

In fact here are the relevant lines:

```
% lsof | head -1
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE       SIZE       NODE NAME
% lsof | grep $pid | grep ' 2w '
java      10047   gpadmin    2w     FIFO                0,6              26854739 pipe
% lsof | grep $pid | grep ' 2w '
java      10047   gpadmin    2w     FIFO                0,6              26854739 pipe
% node=26854739
% lsof | grep $node
postgres  10028   gpadmin   26r     FIFO                0,6              26854739 pipe
sh        10046   gpadmin    2w     FIFO                0,6              26854739 pipe
java      10047   gpadmin    2w     FIFO                0,6              26854739 pipe
```

---

**Details:** The stack dump (jstack -l pid) gives me:

```
2012-04-17 12:23:02
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000061a3800 nid=0x75c5 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"s3gp-2" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaabc207000 nid=0x281f runnable [0x0000000041718000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    - locked <0x00000000f601c4f8> (a java.io.BufferedOutputStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:482)
    - locked <0x00000000f601c4d8> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:104)
    - locked <0x00000000f601c6f0> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:185)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:527)
    - locked <0x00000000f601c4d8> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.append(PrintStream.java:1065)
    at java.io.PrintStream.append(PrintStream.java:57)
    at java.util.Formatter$FixedString.print(Formatter.java:2563)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2476)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    - locked <0x00000000f601c4d8> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader$IOStats.add(Loader.java:136)
    - locked <0x00000000f6015870> (a com.foo.serv.util.Loader$IOStats)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader$Reader.run(Loader.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f6024470> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"s3gp-1" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaabc1fa000 nid=0x281e waiting for monitor entry [0x00000000405d9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader$IOStats.add(Loader.java:129)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000f6015870> (a com.foo.serv.util.Loader$IOStats)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader$Reader.run(Loader.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000f601ea50> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab0054000 nid=0x27e7 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab0051800 nid=0x27e6 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab004e800 nid=0x27e4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab004c000 nid=0x27e3 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab0001000 nid=0x2762 in Object.wait() [0x00000000428cc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000f6015730> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000f6015730> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000005edc800 nid=0x2760 in Object.wait() [0x00000000427cb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000f603b9c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000000f603b9c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e3f800 nid=0x2744 waiting on condition [0x0000000041abe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f61df188> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1433)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader.execute(Loader.java:107)
    at com.foo.serv.util.Loader.main(Loader.java:571)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005ed5000 nid=0x275e runnable

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e4a000 nid=0x2745 runnable

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e4c000 nid=0x2746 runnable

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e4e000 nid=0x2747 runnable

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e4f800 nid=0x2748 runnable

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e51800 nid=0x2749 runnable

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e53800 nid=0x274a runnable

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e55000 nid=0x274b runnable

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e57000 nid=0x274c runnable

"GC task thread#8 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e59000 nid=0x274d runnable

"GC task thread#9 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e5b000 nid=0x274e runnable

"GC task thread#10 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e5c800 nid=0x274f runnable

"GC task thread#11 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e5e800 nid=0x2750 runnable

"GC task thread#12 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000005e60800 nid=0x2751 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab005e800 nid=0x27eb waiting on condition

JNI global references: 207
```

Comment: So `System.err` and `System.out` are not your problem.  The underlying `PrintStream` object is already synchronized.  You don't need to do any locking around them at all.

Comment: @JohnVint `System.err` is a `PrintStream`.

Comment: 1. Is there any chance you're running an endless loop and `System.err` is not really blocking? The relevant code sample would help us eliminate such hypotheses in advance. 2. Is `System.err` by any chance redirected to a sink that can in fact block? May I point out that you don't have a case of a deadlock, but I/O blocking (your thread is RUNNABLE).

Comment: `System.err` and `System.out` often fill up a buffer which is drained by some other process, such as a console, or operating system as the content is streamed to a file.  Have you redirected them to something that needs to be drained?  Is that draining happening in this same process?

Comment: Looks more like the destination of System.err is full than a threading problem in the Java

Comment: @MikeSamuel You may very well be on the right path there.  I'm just going to update the question with those two elements: 1. I use log4j, so it is kind of dumb of me to also use System.err directly.  2. The processes calling the java program are slices of a Greenplum database during a `create external web table ... execute` (to load lots of data quickly). I'm not sure where System.err goes --it was really used to get some stats on the throughput speed during development.

Comment: @mikesamuel I think your answer is correct. If you enter it as answer and not as comment, I could accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I had similar hanging caused by protomatter logger PrintWriterLog which logs errors default to System.err. In my case solution was to handle all logs and redirect them to a file.